# hyperledger peeradmincard creating error ? any solution

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

./createPeerAdminCard.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv11'
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Using composer-cli at v0.19.5

Successfully created business network card file to 
    Output file: /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card

Command succeeded

Error: No connection type provided, probably because the connection profile has no 'x-type' property defined.
Command failed

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an older version of the card (Source:- https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4007)

Comment: The suggested fix is that you need to remove the old fabric-tools directory, and get a later edition of the Fabric dev server tools FIRST, as shown in Step Four of the guide [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)  and then carry out the required steps

Comment: Microtower-PC:~/product-network$ composer network start --networkName product-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network product-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins: 
 userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event

Comment: i got new error when the network Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event
Command failed

Comment: What version of fabric are you running 1.0? ( Composer is v0.19.5 yes?)

Comment: [Composer Release v0.19.5](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases?after=v0.19.6)- According to this, the default for v0.19.5 is Fabric v1.1 and not 1.0. I would suggest updating to fabric v1.1 and trying. (From the provided link- If using the Composer tooling to create a Hyperledger Fabric development server, this will now be creating a v1.1.0 server by default.)

Comment: composer --version
v0.20.5

Comment: Ok thats the latest so i think i get your problem :- /createPeerAdminCard.sh Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh' FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv11' FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Fabric version set to hlfv11. And in the notes of the release (v0.20.5) it says -                                                                                                               
hlfv1 for Fabric v1.0
hlfv11 for Fabric v1.1
hlfv12 for Fabric v1.2
So youre Fabric version should be updated to 1.1 or you can see my next comment

Comment: Write the following in a terminal :- export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv1            .THEN only run the required commands (this lets fabric know you want to run version 1.0) [This used to be the way to do it when i used to use composer]

Comment: ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Unknown chaincodeType: NODE)
Command failed

Comment: I have never gotten such an error but try and follow the steps listed here (https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4043#issuecomment-410521397) AFTER export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv1 (basically teardown old instance and restart)

Comment: bc@bc-HP-Pro-3090-Microtower-PC:~/block-track$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile block-track@0.0.1.bna
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP]
Command failed

Comment: Run 1)StopFabric.sh 2)teardownFabric.sh 3) startFabric.sh 4) createPeerAdmin and after these go to your network and install and start . Let me know if i t helps